# Understanding string appending in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I had the following code:

```
uri = organization_host_url
uri << 'email_check'
target_uri = URI(uri)
```

When this part of code was called repeatedly, `uri` kept the old value and added the new appending part. On the other hand, when I called it alone, it did not keep the old value.

I refactored the code to:

```
uri = organization_host_url + 'email_check'
target_uri = URI(uri)
```

and now `uri` does not keep the old value when repeatedly called.

Why did using the appending option result in `uri` holding the old value?

Comment: Fixing a bug is not refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is setting `uri` to be the *same object* as in `organization_host_url`

```
uri = organization_host_url
```

This is mutating that same object.

```
uri << 'email_check'
```

If you check now, you'll see that both `uri` and `organization_host_url` contain the modified string object.

When you do

```
uri = organization_host_url + 'email_check'
```

`uri` now contains a *different* string object than `organization_host_uri`

You can test this by checking `uri.object_id` and `organization_host_uri.object_id` in the first example, you'll see they have the same object id.

Answer (score 1):

Appending to a string via `<<` will mutate the receiver object, whereas using `+` will not. An example:

```
# Mutating
string1 = 'foo'
string1 << ' bar'
puts string1
# => "foo bar"

# Non-mutating
string2 = string1 + ' baz'
puts string2
# => "foo bar baz"
puts string1
# => "foo bar"
```

In your case, each time the URI append logic is run, it's appending the string directly to the original object, which is why you're experiencing the unwanted chaining of that `email_check` substring on subsequent runs.

Hope this helps!